# Getting current month (full month name - August 04, 2016) format with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have date format: August 04, 2016 how I can get this format to enter in the date field?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
storeEval | monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];  d = new Date(); result = monthNames[d.getMonth()]+' '+ d.getDate() +', ' + d.getFullYear(); result; | date
echo      | ${date}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you use. For example in Java you can use the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) utility with the following pattern:"MMM d,yyyy".